# pgsql - Delete data from huge table where not in

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I need to delete some rows from one large table. The rows to delete shouldn't be in another table, example:

`DELETE FROM LargeTable WHERE id IS NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT foreign_id from EvenLargerTable)`

but my server can't handle such blunt query, because there are almost a million records in the LargeTable and few million records in the EvenLargerTable

How can I solve it?

Comment: The `distinct` in the subquery is useless and will not be optimized away. However that will not improve performance that much. But with just a few million rows, this should work without problems. What exactly is your problem? What do you mean by "the server can't handle" it?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). If your query takes too long (and thus `explain (analyze)` as well), then just show us the execution plan using `explain (verbose)` (without `analyze`). Make sure you preserve the indention in the execution plan.

Comment: Try `DELETE FROM LargeTable WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EvenLargerTable WHERE EvenLargerTable.foreign_id = LargeTable.id);` And I hope you have indexes on both columns?

Comment: @Abelisto 'NOT EXISTS' worked for me, thanks

Comment: Most essential information for a Postgres performance question is missing. Consider instructions in the added tag info.

Comment: @Abelisto - As your suggestion seems to have been the OP's solution, could you move it to an actual answer, so the OP can accept it?

Comment: @RDFozz Done. But with actual execution plan it would be much simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For large tables used for test of existence `NOT EXISTS` frequently works faster then `NOT IN`. So try

```
DELETE FROM LargeTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM EvenLargerTable
  WHERE EvenLargerTable.foreign_id = LargeTable.id);
```

It is hard to explain why it's happening without having actual data. But with simple playground we can see that `NOT IN` case does not used indexes to perform the operation:

Playground:

```
-- drop table if exists a;
-- drop table if exists b;
create table a as select (random()*1000)::int as x from generate_series(1,10000);
create index idx_a on a(x);

create table b as select (random()*1000)::int*10 as x from generate_series(1,1000000);
create index idx_b on b(x);

analyse a;
analyse b;
```

Tests:

```
nd@postgres=# explain (verbose) delete from a where a.x not in (select b.x from b);
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                    QUERY PLAN                                    ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Delete on nd.a  (cost=0.00..129160170.00 rows=5000 width=6)                      ║
║   ->  Seq Scan on nd.a  (cost=0.00..129160170.00 rows=5000 width=6)              ║
║         Output: a.ctid                                                           ║
║         Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))                                                ║
║         SubPlan 1                                                                ║
║           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..23332.00 rows=1000000 width=4)            ║
║                 Output: b.x                                                      ║
║                 ->  Seq Scan on nd.b  (cost=0.00..14425.00 rows=1000000 width=4) ║
║                       Output: b.x                                                ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

nd@postgres=# explain (verbose) delete from a where not exists (select * from b where a.x=b.x);
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                    QUERY PLAN                                    ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Delete on nd.a  (cost=0.42..5005.91 rows=1 width=12)                             ║
║   ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.42..5005.91 rows=1 width=12)                ║
║         Output: a.ctid, b.ctid                                                   ║
║         ->  Seq Scan on nd.a  (cost=0.00..145.00 rows=10000 width=10)            ║
║               Output: a.ctid, a.x                                                ║
║         ->  Index Scan using idx_b on nd.b  (cost=0.42..20.78 rows=999 width=10) ║
║               Output: b.ctid, b.x                                                ║
║               Index Cond: (a.x = b.x)                                            ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is PostgreSQL does not know to handle transactions in a procedure . For this you need to use a trick , to connect in every iteration in the loop. First we need to install db_link :

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

This should add dblink as a valid extension. Most postgres servers have this extension available.

Now having dblink we can run the loop .

```
do $$
<<test1>>
DECLARE v_itteration INTEGER := 1 ; 
DECLARE v_groups    INTEGER := 0 ; 
BEGIN

     SELECT count(*)/10000 INTO v_groups FROM temp_table_what_to_delete ;
     WHILE v_itteration <= v_groups + 1 LOOP
            PERFORM dblink_connect('host=localhost user=your_user password=your_password dbname=your_database');
             perform dblink_exec ( ' DELETE FROM clients WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp_table_what_to_delete limit 10000); ' );
          v_itteration := v_itteration + 1 ;
          PERFORM dblink_disconnect();  
         PERFORM pg_sleep ( 1 ) ;
     END LOOP ;
 end test1 $$;
```

As you see , we delete 10K rows in every iteration . We even sleep for 1 sec to let the server do other stuff. Test and adjust the grouping size as you need.

It would be faster to delete from the temp_table_what_to_delete . Tried to keep the example really simple.