# PostgreSQL - Simple deletes takes more time

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, delete

Today I found a weird(may not be) thing in PostgreSQL 12. Im trying to delete rows from a table with where condition from another. Both are small tables. But the delete is going more than an hour but not completed.

### Row count:

```
convo=> select count(*) from convert  ;
 count
--------
 221368
(1 row)

convo=> select count(*) from gredd  ;
 count
--------
 763150
(1 row)
```

### Index

```
convert  => feed_id - indexed
gredd  => feed_id - primary key
```

### Delete query

```
 delete from convert   where feed_id not in(select feed_id from gredd );
```

### Explain

```
                                    QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on convert  (cost=0.00..15163945284.00 rows=110684 width=6)
   ->  Seq Scan on convert  (cost=0.00..15163945284.00 rows=110684 width=6)
         Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..135098.55 rows=761370 width=6)
                 ->  Seq Scan on gredd  (cost=0.00..128316.70 rows=761370 width=6)
```

Comment: Did you try a `NOT EXISTS` instead?

Comment: like `delete from convert   where feed_id NOT EXISTS (select feed_id from gredd );` ?

Comment: I tried `delete from convert where  NOT EXISTS(select feed_id from gredd ); `  Result: `DELETE 0`

Comment: `delete from convert where not exists (select feed_id from gredd where gredd.feed_id = convert.feed_id)` it should work and faster.

Comment: I'm guessing your query is slow because the `work_mem` is not enough to store the whole `gredd` data in memory. You can test it by change `work_mem` and `limit` , example: `begin; set work_mem = '100MB' ; explain analyse delete from convert where feed_id not in(select feed_id from gredd limit 100000); rollback`

Comment: Yeah I tried this (Ref: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172688/pgsql-delete-data-from-huge-table-where-not-in)  it worked. Any reason why NOT IN took a hell lot of time?